# Website to extract fonts and colors from other sites

Tags: fonts, css, resource-recommendations

I'm looking for a website where you can type in a URL of a site and then the website extracts all the used font-styles and colors used in this particular URL.

The result looks like a kind of Patternlab.

Somebody sent me this link once but now I can't find it anymore. Hope anybody can help!

Answer (score 5):

I don't have an information about that website, but I have found some plugins, that may you help find fonts and colors on websites.

1. Firefox addon, called Font Finder => [LINK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/font-finder/)

You just need to click it and it shows you all the information about website.
[image]

2. If you are using Chrome, you could also download plugin, called WhatFont => [LINK](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatfont/jabopobgcpjmedljpbcaablpmlmfcogm)

It works very good, showing also font-size, style, etc.
[image]

3. For the colors, I recommend you this website => [Color Combos](https://www.colorcombos.com/)

Type an URL on the "Grab Website Colors" panel, click OK, and then you have to wait a looong time, depend on the "size" of the website of course.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately it is not exactly what i am searching for. But thanks a lot anyway :)

Answer (score 4):

A colleague of mine just found the Page. *hurray*

**It's**: http://stylifyme.com/

You can also see the Project here: https://github.com/micmro/Stylify-Me

Answer (score 0):

There is a browser extension call Colors and Fonts Extractor
That does extacly that and then allows you to export them as CSS variables
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/colors-and-fonts-extractor/

Answer (score 0):

https://alwane.io It is a web-based tool giving you the ability to extract colors from a website URL or an existing CSS code, regroup/order colors, then generate a palette including a CSS/Sass file. A simple and handy tool to build your next project's colors, get inspiration, and examine your website's color palette.

[image]